# Rails yield header issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

i currently loading header layout on application as follow:

```
<% content_for :header do %>
  <p>A simple page</p>
<% end %>
```

and on my application layout i call the yield :header as follow:

```
<body>
<%= yield :header %>
<%= yield %>

</body>
```

Look so simple, but the header portion is not rendering. What might be issues here?

Comment: In which template/partial are you calling `<% content_for :header do %>`? Are you sure that template/partial is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

`content_for` must be placed BEFORE yield. Therfore you can't `yield :header` based on view.